# Unable to get Consul Connect to work with Nomad

Tags: docker, consul, envoyproxy, nomad

I'm trying to get Consul Connect side car envoy to work but the health checks for sidecar keeps failing.

I'm using following versions of Consul and Nomad

```
Consul : 1.7.3
Nomad : 0.11.1
CNI Plugins : 0.8.6
```

My setup looks like follows.

**1 Consul Server running consul in docker container.**

```
docker run -d --net=host --name=server -v /var/consul/:/consul/config consul:1.7 agent -server -ui -node=server-1 -bind=$internal_ip -ui -bootstrap-expect=1 -client=0.0.0.0
```

`internal_ip` is the internal IP address of my GCP VM.

**1 Nomad Server with Consul Agent in client mode**

```
nohup nomad agent -config=/etc/nomad.d/server.hcl &

docker run -d --name=consul-client --net=host -v ${volume_path}:/consul/config/ consul:1.7 agent -node=$node_name -bind=$internal_ip -join=${server_ip} -client=0.0.0.0
```

`interal_ip` is the internal IP address of GCP VM and `server_ip` is the internal IP address of Server VM.

**2 Nomad Client with Consul Agent in client mode**

```
nohup nomad agent -config=/etc/nomad.d/client.hcl &

 docker run -d --name=consul-client --net=host -v ${volume_path}:/consul/config/ consul:1.7 agent -node=$node_name -bind=$internal_ip -join=${server_ip} -client=0.0.0.0
```

**On Nomad clients, I also have `consul` binary available in path.**

Now I'm trying to deploy the sample Nomad and Consul Connect job from [here](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/integrations/consul-connect/)

```
    job "countdash" {
      datacenters = ["dc1"]

      group "api" {
        network {
          mode = "bridge"
        }

        service {
          name = "count-api"
          port = "9001"

          connect {
            sidecar_service {}
          }
        }

        task "web" {
          driver = "docker"

          config {
            image = "hashicorpnomad/counter-api:v1"
          }
        }
      }

      group "dashboard" {
        network {
          mode = "bridge"

          port "http" {
            static = 9002
            to     = 9002
          }
        }

        service {
          name = "count-dashboard"
          port = "9002"

          connect {
            sidecar_service {
              proxy {
                upstreams {
                  destination_name = "count-api"
                  local_bind_port  = 8080
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

        task "dashboard" {
          driver = "docker"

          env {
            COUNTING_SERVICE_URL = "http://${NOMAD_UPSTREAM_ADDR_count_api}"
          }

          config {
            image = "hashicorpnomad/counter-dashboard:v1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The docker container for service and sidecar gets started and gets registered in Consul, but I'm unable to access any of the service.

[image]

I SSH onto the Nomad Client node and can see the container running.

[image]

1. Odd thing I noticed is that I cannot see port forwarded to the host
2. I cannot access it via curl from host.

I tried doing `curl $internal_ip:9002` but it didn't work.

I checked if Nomad created any new bridge network since that's what I used as `mode` in the `network stanza` but there are no new networks.

[image]

Is there anything that I'm missing in my setup ?

Comment: have you checked the nomad logs from your docker container? I think consul connect needs to edit iptables rules and your container doesn't have `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN`, that should be failing and maybe there are other errors in the nomad logs?

Comment: @maxm I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `COUNTING_SERVICE_URL = "http://${NOMAD_UPSTREAM_ADDR_count_api}"` to `COUNTING_SERVICE_URL = "http://localhost:8080"`, since that is the local bind port that the envoy proxy will be listening on to forward traffic to the count-api.

An example of a working connect setup can be found at https://github.com/hashicorp/video-content/tree/master/nomad-connect-integration/nomad_jobs

Comment: I'll give it a try.